# Get results for EXECUTE(@QUERY) and FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a dynamic query with FOR XML clause.
How can I get result from it ?

```
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Here dynamicaly generated query. But for example i made it static
SET @QUERY = N'SELECT [CLMN]
FROM (
        SELECT 1 as [CLMN]
    ) TBL FOR XML PATH(''TBL'')';

EXECUTE(@QUERY);
```

I need insert result to any variable from this code:

```
EXECUTE(@QUERY);
```

Comment: What exactly is your question -- execute will return the results just like running a native query would.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
declare @QUERY nvarchar(max), @RESULT xml

set @QUERY = N'select @RESULT = (
    SELECT [CLMN]
    FROM (
        SELECT 1 as [CLMN]
    ) TBL 
    FOR XML PATH(''TBL'')
)'

execute sp_executesql @QUERY, N'@RESULT xml output', @RESULT = @RESULT output

select @RESULT
```

Just pass outer variable into dynamic query, and assign result of `select ... for xml` to this variable in query.